# Count digits for -1 return 12 instead of 32

Tags: python

For the following simple function to calculate the number of 1 in a 32-bit integer, it is expected to return 32 for input -1, but got 12 instead.

```
class Solution:
    def bitNum(self, n):
        bm = {
            0:0, 1:1, 2:1, 3:2, 4:1, 5:2, 6:2, 7:3,
            8:1, 9:2, 10:2, 11:3, 12:2, 13:3, 14:3, 
            15:4
            }
        return bm[n & 0xF] + bm[(n>>4) & 0xF] + bm[(n>>8) & 0xF]
        + bm[(n>>12) & 0xF] + bm[(n>>16) & 0xF] + bm[(n>>20) & 0xF]
        + bm[(n>>24) & 0xF] + bm[(n>>28) & 0xF]
```

But if a var is used to store the result, and split plus to several parts, the correct answer will be returned. Why?

```
class Solution:
    def bitNum(self, n):
        bm = {
            0:0, 1:1, 2:1, 3:2, 4:1, 5:2, 6:2, 7:3,
            8:1, 9:2, 10:2, 11:3, 12:2, 13:3, 14:3, 
            15:4
            }
        bits =  bm[n & 0xF]
        bits += bm[(n>>4) & 0xF] + bm[(n>>8) & 0xF]
        bits += bm[(n>>12) & 0xF] + bm[(n>>16) & 0xF] + bm[(n>>20) & 0xF]
        bits += bm[(n>>24) & 0xF] + bm[(n>>28) & 0xF]
        return bits
```

Answer (score 2):

may be to surround all into '(' and ')'? :)
Or to use backslash at line end:

```
return (a + b
+ c + d)
```

Comment: Thanks Paul! yes, that works. I guess python ignore lines after return if there is no "\" in the end